# Why is my damage so different?

Tags: mass-effect

I'm playing Mass Effect 1 for the second time with an imported character (Infiltrator, level 45).

Sometimes I one-shot every enemy that is in line of sight, but sometimes only their shield lightens up and they take almost no damage - even if I shoot them several times.

Is this a bug or do some enemies have advanced levels?

Summary of my question:

My shots even manage to kill a stationary geth shield and the geth behind the shield (both with full hp), but sometimes the issue as described above happens. 
I have to use another weapon and shoot several times until the enemy dies.

Comment: do you have any shield piercing mods on your weapon?

Comment: Nope, always used the same sniper gun (doesn't remember the name, sorry) + explosive shells (you even don't need to hit exactly...)

Answer (score 1):

enemies do have advanced levels, and some of them get more damage from a specified weapon vs others, and weapon mods impact your damage as well.